# Tailwind CSS Custom Font didn't work on other devices

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css

The problem of custom font from local machine didn't work i found when i deployed my web and try to open it on my phone, i've been searching for the solutions to make the font works globally but it's to no avail. Here's my assumption of what cause the issues:

1. In my pc used to develop the web, the custom font works like i expected, in both development and production stage. But this is different when i'm using my phone, this is probably because my phone don't have the font installed on the local machine yet (since i need to install the custom font first on my pc to make the local font works).

Is this behavior expected when using local fonts? If yes, what's the best way to make the font work on all devices without the need to install font on each devices? If no, what do you think causes this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to host your font somewhere, then link to that hosted version of your font. If your font is just downloaded locally on your computer, then other people can't access it. Check out how to use Google Fonts in your site for an idea of how to do this.

Comment: Ah that's why, i thought when i build the web it was automatically compiled with the custom font. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use google fonts as an alternative

- In main.css

  ```
    @import url('font-from-google-font');

    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
  ```
- In tailwind.config.js

  ```
    module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'], // example with react
      theme: {
        fontFamily: {
          sans: ['your-font-google'],
        },
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
  ```

Tailwind font family documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family